# SwiftUI: Bar button item is not at top of navigation bar in tab view

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have 2 screens, one with a `NavigationView` to make a navigation bar, and one with a `TabView`. In the `TabView`, I added a bar button item icon for each tab using `ToolbarItem` inside a new `NavigationView`, but when I run my app, the icon shows up in the middle of the navigation bar, instead of at the top.

What do I change to make the bar button items appear at the top of a navigation bar?

First screen:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(Color(.systemGreen))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 30) {
                NavigationLink(destination: HomeView()) {
                    Text("Go to tabs screen")
                }
            }.padding(20)
        }
    }
}
```

Second screen:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Tab 1")
                    .padding(.leading, 30)
                }
                
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Button(action: {
                            print("person icon pressed")
                            }, label: {
                                Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle").imageScale(.large)
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
                
            }.tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "list.bullet")
                    .font(.system(size: 26))
                Text("Tab 1")
            }
            
            
            
            NavigationView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Tab 2")
                }
                
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Button(action: {
                                print("Plus icon pressed.")
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus").imageScale(.large)
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
                
            }.tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "books.vertical")
                    .font(.system(size: 26))
                Text("Tab 2")
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

---

This is what they look like in iPhone 11 simulator:

[image: First screen with NavigationView]
[image: Second screen with TabView and icons in middle not top]

But I want the icons to be at the top like they're shown in Preview:

[image: Preview icons are at top]

Comment: Don’t put a navigation view inside a navigation view. You create a second level of navigation. For the button, the button should be set using ToolBarIten position at trailing if it is what you want. Same as UIKit : one navigation controller then each view controller can set the navigation bat contents.

Comment: Then just to confirm, I should make only one navigation view, and depending on which view I have change its bar contents?

Comment: Yes. The navigation view is a container to handle navigation via navigation links. It is the responsibility of linked views to update title, toolbar according its own contents.